# Get green color to disappear or be transparent

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, pixel

This is the code for highlighting differences in an image.

This is the resulting image it generates.
![enter image description here][1]

How do I get the green parts highlighted to disappear or be transparent. I only want the yellow present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something like

```
if (diff != 0) {
    r1 = g1 = 0xff;
}
```

This will make any differences be shown as solid yellow. Right now there's nothing to ensure that the output color will have any red in it (leaving it as pure green).

Edit:
To remove all the green, not change it to the yellow, something like this should work:

```
if (diff != 0 && Math.abs(r1-r2)>=Math.abs(b1)) {
    r1 = Math.abs(r1 - r2); 
    g1 = Math.abs(b1);
    b1 = 0;
}
```

This will only mark the changes if the difference in reds is the same as, or larger than the amount of blue, so that the output will have at least as much red as green

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your response! What I really wanted to know was if there was a way to make the green color disappear or transparent.. not to make it yellow. Thanks!

Comment: @user3078335 ah, okay. I updated my answer to hopefully be what you want.